# Can I make IEMobile not strip the # from the URL of a redirect?

Tags: http, http-headers, ie-mobile

I am having an issue with IEMobile accessing my site.  A certain redirect I use has a 302 response code, and the headers (yep, that's app-engine):

```
Server         Development/1.0 Python/2.5.2
Date           Tue, 04 Nov 2008 16:47:02 GMT
Content-Type   text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control  no-cache
Location       http://localhost/games/edit-game.html?game=110&frame_to_edit=3#input-top
Content-Length 0
```

This works fine for most browsers.  Enter IEMobile (via Windows Mobile 6.1).  Upon receiving this response, IEMobile heads to

```
http://localhost/games/edit-game.html?game=110&frame_to_edit=3
```

Note the missing `#input-top`.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading RFC2616 it specifies

> Location: absoluteURI

where absolute URI is defined by [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

Tracing the definition of absoluteURI, the # character is not part of the URI definition, this is confirmed by section 4.1

> 4.1. Fragment Identifier
>
> When a URI reference is used to
>   perform a retrieval action on the
>   identified resource, the optional
>   fragment identifier, separated from
>   the URI by a crosshatch ("#")
>   character, consists of additional
>   reference information to be
>   interpreted by the user agent after
>   the    retrieval action has been
>   successfully completed.  As such, it
>   is not    part of a URI, but is often
>   used in conjunction with a URI.

In short, the #fragment is *not* part of the URI, and is being stripped by the browser as not part of the Location: header.

Comment: This is a bug in RFC 2616. See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/6. It will be fixed in the next revision (check http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-08.html#rfc.section.9.4)

Answer (score 0):

Dave is right, googling comes up with some the same issue.

Ugly workaround : use a meta refresh tag instead of redirect if you want to support that browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's little you can do; it appears to be a bug in your browser (the implementers apparently have missed an RFC 2616 erratum).